# Sync sent items from a POP3 account on Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, exchange

I'm using Thunderbird for my work email account, which is powered on Microsoft Exchange I think. I'm OK with sending and receiving messages. However all the sent messages are in Thunderbird only. Is there a way to sync them into my real sent box, so that I'll be able to view them on the web mail on the browser?

Comment: Is using IMAP an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.  POP3 and SMTP were designed back when storage was much more expensive, and nothing was typically left server-side.  If your email is indeed coming from Exchange, you should be able to use IMAP, as long as your employer is allowing access to it.  If your employer is running Exchange 2007 or 2010, there is also an EWS (Exchange Web Services) plugin called [ExQuilla](https://exquilla.zendesk.com/home) that will allow for a somewhat more native connection (I believe this is similar to how Android and iOS devices connect).  If I'm understanding it correctly, ExQuilla would allow Thunderbird to function more like Outlook, including Global Address Book support.

If you do set up an EWS or IMAP connection, it should then be possible to copy/move everything from your local sent box to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much ND for the detailed explanation. I think the Exchange service I'm using is called OWA. Do you think if I can set up the account again but using IMAP in Thunderbird, which means same email account 2 methods IMAP and POP3. Then Can I possibly drag all the sent items from the POP3 one into the IMAP one? Is that doable and will it sync all the items to the web account please?

Comment: OWA stands for Outlook Web Interface.  You may be referring to the server name, which may be something like owa.companysite.com.  If that's the case, yes, you can probably just create a new IMAP account.  Once it's created, you should be able to drag the sent items from the POP3 folder locally to the IMAP sent folder.  Be aware that if you have a large number of messages, this could take a long time depending on your upload speed.  This is best done on the office network, if possible.

Comment: I'll double check with my work mates, I think some of them are using IMAP. It's good to know that could work. I assume there won't be any problem of having POP3 and IMAP on the same account at the same time? And thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you're not deleting from the server when you download via POP3 (which, based on your original question is what it sounds like), no. You will be doing duplicate downloading, though, which may be a concern depending on your internet connection (speed, limits, etc.).  It also means you'd be storing every message twice (once in the local storage for the POP3 account and once in the local storage for the IMAP account). I'd recommend disabling the POP3 connection once you have the IMAP connection configured.

Comment: I'm sure all the inbox items are remaining in the web account. I don't mind duplicate downloading all the messages, the connection at work is very very fast. Yes, I'm thinking the same, once I get the sent items and IMAP sorted out I'm willing to disable/remove the POP3 account. Thanks!